# System of linear equations using calculus

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

Find $\ ax^3+bx^2+cx+d, \ rel.\max \ (3,3), \ rel.\min \ (5,1), \ $ inflection  point 
 $(4,2)$

Why the system of linear equations

$27a+9b+3c+d=3,\ 125a+25b+5c+d=1,\ 27a+6b+c=0,\ 24a+2b=0$

can be solved, but if you replace $27a+6b+c=0$ with valid $64a+16b+4c+d=2$ it doesn't?

Comment: It looks like you have two problems here. Which one gives you trouble? What have you done so far?

Comment: It does appear to come from one question, but is very unclearly stated.  Presumably one is to find $a,b,c,d$ so the three points given are characterized correctly.  Do you know where the equations come from?  What have you tried?  I haven't tried to solve them, but I don't understand what you are asking at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$

- local maximum in $(3,3)$ needs  $f(3)=3$ and $f'(3)=0$
- local minimum in $(5,1)$ needs  $f(5)=1$ and $f'(5)=0$
- inflexion point in $(4,2)$ needs  $f(4)=2$ and $f''(4)=0$

Now let's examine your claim

system $\{f(3)=3,\ f(5)=1,\ f'(3)=0,\ f''(4)=0\}$ is solvable

- Indeed I get solution $\{a = \frac 12, b = -6, c = \frac{45}2, d = -24\}\tag{1}$

system $\{f(3)=3,\ f(5)=1,\ f(4)=2,\ f''(4)=0\}$ is not solvable

- I do not agree, there are many solutions $\{a = \frac {6-d}{60}, b = \frac {d-6}5, c = \frac{222-47d}{60}, d \}\tag{2}$

In this case, the system is loose, and we get an infinite number of possibilities according to the free value we choose for $d$. In fact, there are just not enough conditions to determine $d$.

But this is compatible with the solution found previously when you set $d=-24$.

I let you check it, but the whole system

$\{f(3)=3,\ f(5)=1,\ f(4)=2,\ f'(3)=0,\ f'(5)=0,\ f''(4)=0\}$

is consistent and the solution found in $(1)$ applies.

---

*Edit: answer to OP question in comment.*

The fact that the system becomes loose in the second case comes from the definition of derivation.

$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$

And similarly for second derivative we have $f''(x)=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$.

This symmetric formula is not true for all functions, but it is for polynomials.

And even more specifically it happens that for polynomials of degree $3$ then the formula is exact without taking the limit.

- $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\implies f''(x)=\dfrac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$

Coming to our example, let set $h=1$ and $x=4$ and you get $$f''(4)=f(3)-2f(4)+f(5)=3-2\times 2+1=0$$

This why this condition is always fulfilled.

The middle point is automatically an inflexion point, when the value of $f$ in this point is also the average of the values of $f$ taken at the extremities:

$f\left(\dfrac{3+5}2\right)=\dfrac{f(3)+f(5)}2$

So basically you have a cubic polynomial with $4$ unknowns coefficients and $3$ equations $\{f(3)=3,f(4)=2,f(5)=1\}$ thus a loose system.

And adding $f''(4)=0$ doesn't bring new information, so the system stays loose.

But the info that one point is a local extremum, resolves the system (and note that the inflexion point, makes then the symmetrical of that extremum an opposite extremum (i.e min$\leftrightarrow$max).

Comment: why there is no unique solution in second case? what makes it loose?

Comment: @BiSector answered your concern.

Answer (score 0):

let $$f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$ tehn  we have
$$f'(x)=3ax^2+2bx+c$$
$$f''(x)=6ax+2b$$ and we get from the conditions:
$$f(3)=27a+9b+3c+d=3$$
$$f'(3)=27a+6b+c=0$$
$$f(5)=125a+25b+5c+d=1$$
$$f'(5)=75a+10b+c=0$$
$$f(4)=64a+16b+4c+d=2$$
$$f''(4)=24a+2b=0$$
can you solve this?